# Are you able to calculate daily and log returns with a renamed column?

Tags: python, pandas, return, attributeerror, summary

Student back here again with some help needed.

I'm back on the Python train and I'm honestly enjoying it a lot more now, and I've had a lot of help from really nice people online here. But back to my question. I've downloaded the historical data for a certain stock, and I'm renaming their adjusted close and volume to "PRC", and "Vol" respectively. I want to calculate their daily return, log daily return and growth rate, but it seems like there's an attributing error that I don't know what to do with. My Codes attached below.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
import numpy as np


# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("QQQ", start="2005-01-01", end="2011-12-31")

data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "prc", "Volume": "vol"})

data['simple_rtn'] = data.prc.pct_change()
data['log_rtn'] = np.log(df.prc/df.prc.shift(1))
```

Running this gives me this error - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'prc'

Essentially, I want to find out the simple, log return, % growth rate of trading volume, and grab a full summary of all the column.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "prc", "Volume": "vol"})
```

Are you sure this grammer is correct ?
Try to print column names after this command.

Comment: Huh. you're right. When I print the column names it stays as Adj Close and Volume, but if I simply type Data and run it, it will give me PRC and Vol instead.

Comment: I guess you should try another column renaming method.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "prc", "Volume": "vol"}, inplace=True)
```

add `inplace = True` to make the columns name changed as you expected.